# Create new Columns based on values in existing Columns and merge Rows

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

My dataframe contains a column of IDs and a column of subjects. Ultimately, I would like to cluster my data by subject so I can see groups of IDs clustered by the Subjects taken.

In order to do that I would like to end up with my data frame as one row per ID, with one column per subject containing a 1 or 0 value to indicate if that subject was taken by the ID on that row.

**Input example:**

```
ID      Subject
John    History
John    English
Jane    Maths
Jane    Science
Jane    History
Mark    History
Mark    Science
Mark    Mathematics
```

**Expected output:**

```
Subject  English  History  Mathematics  Maths  Science
ID                                                    
Jane           0        1            0      1        1
John           1        1            0      0        0
Mark           0        1            1      0        1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do the following using [pivot_table()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html)

```
 df.pivot_table(index='ID', columns='Subject', aggfunc=len,fill_value=0)
```

Comment: Thank you this worked really well for me, much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `crosstab`:

```
pd.crosstab(df['ID'], df['Subject'])
```

Output:

```
Subject  English  History  Mathematics  Maths  Science
ID                                                    
Jane           0        1            0      1        1
John           1        1            0      0        0
Mark           0        1            1      0        1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to reshape your dataframe from ["stacked" format to "pivot" format](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/reshaping.html).
But first you have to aggregate your data.

Try something like this:

```
agg_df = df.groupby(["ID", "Subject"]).count().reset_index(name="count")
agg_df.pivot(index='ID', columns='Subject', values='count')
```